# Connection Error: Not able to connect to Azure SQL Server database using nestjs typeorm

Tags: sql-server, azure, nestjs, connection, typeorm

We are migrating to Azure asp and are trying to connect to  SQL Server database without username, password and running into the error as mentioned below:

- Node v18
- typeorm: 0.3.20
- mssql 10.0.2

Am I using the correct options to connect? Any advice would be greatly appreciated

```
//config-service.ts
import { TypeOrmModuleOptions } from '@nestjs/typeorm';
import { Injectable } from '@nestjs/common';

@Injectable()
export class TypeOrmLoggerService implements TypeOrmOptionsFactory {
createTypeOrmOptions(): TypeOrmModuleOptions {
    return {
        type: 'mssql',
        host: process.env.SQLSERVER,
        database: process.env.SQLDATABASE,
        port: Number(1433),
        synchronize: false,
        logging: true,
        entities: ['./entity-path'],
        connectionTimeout: Number(30000),
        options: { encrypt: true }
        authentication: {
            type: "azure-active-directory-msi-app-service",
            options: {
                clientId: ""
                msiEndpoint: process.env.MSI_ENDPOINT,
                msiSecret: process.env.MSI_SECRET,
            }
        }
    }
}};

//app.module.ts
import { TypeOrmLoggerService} from ./db/db.config.service';
@Module({
imports: [ConfigModule.forRoot,
TypeOrmModule.forRootAsync({useClass:TypeOrmLoggerService}),
],
})
export class AppModule {}
```

Error I am getting on console after using the above mentioned code is:

> ConnectionError: Login failed for user 'token-identified-principal'.

Comment: Rolled back to your edits. Thanks @DaleK

Answer (score 0):

> ConnectionError: Login failed for user 'token-identified-principal'.

As per this [MS document](https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/azure-database-support-blog/aad-auth-error-login-failed-for-user-lt-token-identified/ba-p/1417535), if the user is not valid in the database or if the user is not the AAD Server Admin, you may get the above error while connecting to the database.

Create the user in the database by logging in to the SQL Server with an administrator account, adding a user to the database, and assigning a role to the user:

```cs
create user [<appName>] from external provider;
alter role db_datareader add member [<appName>];
alter role db_datawriter add member [<appName>];
```

[image]

Along with that, make sure you have given the correct database name where the user is created while connecting.

For more information, you can refer to [this](https://medium.com/@swagatachaudhuri/implement-azure-ad-authentication-in-nest-js-1fe947da2c99).